# Hybrid QuickSort + Insertion sort java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, algorithm, stack-overflow, quicksort, insertion-sort

I am trying to calculate the running time of hybrid quickSort - insertionSort. However, when presented with a larger array (~500k elements), I get a java.lang.StackOverflowError. Can I somehow overcome this? Not using recursion is not an option.

Here's the code:

```
public class QuickSort2 {

private static void swap(int[] arr, int x, int y){
       int temp = arr[x];
       arr[x] = arr[y];
       arr[y] = temp;
    }

private static int partition(int[] arr, int lo, int hi){
    int pivot = arr[hi];
    int index = lo - 1;
    for(int i = lo; i < hi; i++){
        if(arr[i] < pivot){
            index++;
            swap(arr, index, i);
        }
    }
    swap(arr, index + 1, hi);
    return index + 1;
} 

public static void quickSort(int[] arr, int lo, int hi){
    if(lo < hi && hi-lo > 10){
        int q = partition(arr, lo, hi);
        quickSort(arr,lo,q-1);
        quickSort(arr,q+1,hi);
        }else{
            InsertionSort.insertSort(arr);
        }    
    }
}
```

and also, the insertionSort:

```
public class InsertionSort {

static void insertSort(int[] arr){
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++){
        int key = arr[j];
        int i = j-1;
        while ((i >= 0) && (arr[i] > key)){
            arr[i+1] = arr[i];
            i--;
        }
        arr[i+1] = key;
    }         
}
```

The lines where the error occurs:

```
quickSort(arr,lo,q-1);
quickSort(arr,q+1,hi);
```

and also the calling code:

```
public class RunningTime {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = ReadTest.readToArray("int500k");
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = arr.length - 1;

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    QuickSort2.quickSort(arr, lo, hi);
    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Running time: " + elapsedTime);
    System.out.println("Array is sorted: " + isSorted(arr));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should restrict insertion sort to work only on the subset of the array.

Besides this, I don't see any other issues with your code.

Is the file `int500k` sorted? If so this is the worst case scenario for quick sort, which means that the recursion will be 500k levels deep.

To fix it you can for instance choose the pivot randomly instead of `arr[hi]`.

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle yes that's what I thought. Strange... Does the quicksort work without the insertion sort at all? And does it work (not fail with an exception) if insertSort is an empty method?

Comment: Still a StackOverflowError if insertSort is an empty method. So I don't think insertSort is the problem here.

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle does the quicksort work if insertSort is an empty method and you remove `&& hi-lo > 10`?

Comment: It works for a maximum of 14444 elements. Any higher and it won't. I admit, it's a little strange....

Comment: The file `int500k` is not sorted. Quicksort without the insertion sort works just fine - even when we pivot is not chosen randomly.

Comment: @meriam That's interesting... could you post an update to the question with the insertSort fixed to work only on `lo..hi`?

Comment: Yes! When insertSort is fixed to work with lo..hi, it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @meriam that's because the first time insertSort was invoked it sorted the whole array, thus leading to worst-case scenario for quicksort